# How to count hidden columns in excel file using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

If anyone can know how to **count visible columns only** in excel using c#?

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
```

I have hidden columns in WorkSheet and I do not know how to count.

**range.Columns.Count** It does not work when I have hidden columns

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `Hidden` is a property of cells not of columns. So if you want to count the number of hidden columns you can count the number of hidden cells in the first row representative by subtracting the number of visible cells from the number of all cells.

```
Excel.Range firstRow = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1)
int count = firstRow.Cells.Count - firstRow.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
```

(I don't know if my C# syntax is correct but I think you understand what I mean)